# PDO connection to ODBC iseries not working

Tags: php, pdo, db2, odbc, ibm-midrange

I'm trying to convert my odbc_connect to a PDO connection and I keep getting an error. Before it was a driver error but I fixed my php.ini file to use the odbc PDO.

Here is what I'm successfully connecting with now:

```
//Establish DB2 Connection  
$DB2Conn = odbc_connect("webConn","testuser", "test");
```

I'm trying the below for the PDO but it's saying that `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[08S01] SQLDriverConnect: 11001 [IBM][System i Access ODBC Driver]Communication link failure. comm rc=11001 - CWBCO1004 - Remote address could not be resolved' in`

Connection test:

```
//PDO COnnections
$DB2conn = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={iSeries Access ODBC Driver};SYSTEM=webconn;", $username, $password);
```

I'm new to DB2 connections anyway and I've never had to use PDO with it. the docs help a bit but I'm stuck now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to PHP [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-connect.php), `odbc_connect` uses following arguments to connect to a data source:

> resource odbc_connect ( string $dsn , string $user , string $password [, int $cursor_type ] )

Since you did not specify *Driver* in you `odbc_connect()`, you are using a *DSN* (i.e., Data Source Name). Therefore, adjust PDO to connect to same DSN, *webConn*:

```
$DB2Conn  = new PDO("odbc:DSN=webConn;", $username, $password);
```